# How to open multiple blank windows in Javascrript?

Tags: javascript

Currently this code but it is only opening 1 window.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("www.google.com", "_blank", "width=200,height=100", false);
  var myWindow2 = window.open("www.facebook.com", "_blank", "width=200,height=100", false);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

[I also tried this on w3school but does not work.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open2)

Comment: Make sure that your browser isn't blocking any of the pop-up windows (if on chrome, you'll see a little square with an "x" on it indicating that it has blocked the popup)

Comment: It’s likely to stop spam from opening multiple windows at once.

Comment: it should open two windows. it's working fine in my console too. Are you sure it is not opening on top of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to assign variables to it to work, the following should do fine.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('First one firing...');
  window.open("www.google.com", "_blank", "width=200,height=100", false);
  console.log('Second one firing...');
  window.open("www.facebook.com", "_blank", "width=200,height=100", false);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

When I tried this snippet, it seems to work. You might need to configure the browser to allow popups, which might be the issue (I initially got an error saying

> Blocked opening 'https://stacksnippets.net/www.google.com' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set."

This will likely mean that you are either hitting a popup window limit in a browser or you are just blocking them altogether. You could try to put a "wait" in if it is a rate-limit issue with whatever browser you are looking for.

Comment: how to configure it?

Comment: This will depend on what browser you are using. For Chrome it will be this: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20mitigate%20the,creating%20a%20clean%20browsing%20context , but only for the sandbox itself.

Comment: Thanks @AaronMorefield. Is there a way to make the window.open() windows to show in the same tab?

Comment: @AaronMorefield ok, you weren't clear enough then, you wrote "configure the snippet", so I thought you can do it from the inside, not in the browser.

Comment: Sorry about that, @FlashThunder, I will correct that presently!